# Не выводится List в консоль

Tags: c#, list, консоль

Не получается вывести List  в консоль, не ругается, просто не выводит.

Вот коды:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gallows
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char letter; // буква, вводимая игроком с консоли

            string word = Console.ReadLine(); // игровое слово 

            List<char> wordList = word.ToList(); // массив букв из игрового слова

            List<char> consList = new List<char>(wordList.Count); // слово в консоли

            int errors = 0; // количство ошибок

            int gameResult = 0; // статус игры(0 - игра идет, -1 - проигрыш, 1 - победа)

            Methods method = new Methods(); // экземпляр класс для использования методов

            for(int i = 0; i < consList.Count; i++) // скрываем буквы в консоли
            {
                consList[i] = '_';
            }

            while(gameResult == 0)
            {
                method.Info(consList, errors);

                letter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

                gameResult = method.CheckErrors(errors);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

И второй класс:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gallows
{
    class Methods
    {
        public int CheckErrors(int errors)
        {
            if(errors == 7)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public void Info(List<char> consList, int errors)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < consList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(consList[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Количество ошибок: {errors}");
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите решить эту проблему.

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь отладчиком?

Comment: Поддержу комментарий выше, а так `List<char> consList = new List<char>(wordList.Count);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот кусок кода не работает.

```
List<char> consList = new List<char>(wordList.Count); // слово в консоли
```

поменяйте на

```
List<char> wordList = word.ToList(); // массив букв из игрового слова

List<char> consList = new List<char>(); // слово в консоли

for (int i = 0; i < wordList.Count; i++) // скрываем буквы в консоли
{
    consList.Add('_');
}
```

и можете дальше править ошибки в логике игры